# how to use separated encoded polylines in a map using google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, encode, polyline, google-polyline

Anyone knows why, compared to version v2, in v3 of google maps api using, in a single map, multiple encoded polylines, i view them as an unique (joined) path?

as you can see here http://www.campiscout.com/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=37  in v2 i'm able to push them perfectly separated.

my test website with v3 version is here: http://www.zupa.it/joomla25/hike-route-trekking

encoded paths are stored in a mysql db, and they are passed to maps via xml

is there a solution to my problem?
is it a bug or i made some mistake or forgot somethings?

after some weeks pasted on the net searching for a solution, I will appreciate any help.

thanks in advance.

B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 global variable **tempPoly** there and you extend the path of this polyline in addLocation with all locations of all markers.

Use this to create the polyline inside the callback of downloadUrl():

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
   strokeColor: '#FF3333',
   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   path: decodedPath,
   map:map
});
```

...and remove this from **addLocation()**:

```
tempPoly.setPath(latlngs);
```

Comment: Thank Dr.Molle, i've solved my problem deleting the addLocation() function, restudying the global variables and using "path:" instead of "location:" option in polyline initialization. Thank you so much.